# Java mouse events do not translate coordinates properly when zooming with mouse wheel

Tags: java

I need some assistance figuring out how to translate coordinates from mouse events during zoom ... it works when zoom factor is 1.0 but not sure of algorithm when it changes...

I can drag the rectangle around the screen when if I comment out the zoom code but once zoom, the mouse coordinates screw up once the zoom is applied

I just cannot figure out the coordinates translation code

```
package ca.stackoverflow.main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Demo() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new Panel());
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Demo demo = new Demo();
                    demo.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(Throwable e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final double MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR = 0.1;
    private static final double MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR = 5.0;

    private Color _fillColor;
    private Point _startPoint;
    private double xOffset;
    private double yOffset;

    private int xdragOffset;
    private int ydragOffset;    
    
    private double zoomFactor = 1;
    private double prevZoomFactor = 1;
    private boolean zoomer;
        
    private Rectangle _rectangle;

    public Panel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
        _rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 200);
    }

    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

        if (zoomer) {

            double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
            double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();
            double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;
            xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * xRel;
            yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * yRel;
            prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
            zoomer = false;
        }
        
        at.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
        at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        g2.transform(at);
        
        
        g.setColor(_fillColor);
        g.fillRect(_rectangle.x, _rectangle.y, _rectangle.width, _rectangle.height);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(_rectangle.x, _rectangle.y, _rectangle.width, _rectangle.height);      
    }

    @Override public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
        if(_rectangle.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            _fillColor = Color.GREEN;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        _startPoint = null;
        _fillColor = Color.WHITE;

        if(_rectangle.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            _startPoint = e.getPoint();
            _fillColor = Color.GREEN;
            xdragOffset = _startPoint.x - _rectangle.x;
            ydragOffset = _startPoint.y - _rectangle.y;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    
    @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(_startPoint != null) {
            int diffX = e.getX() - _startPoint.x;
            int diffY = e.getY() - _startPoint.y;
            
            _rectangle.x = _startPoint.x + diffX - xdragOffset;  
            _rectangle.y = _startPoint.y + diffY - ydragOffset;  
        }
        else {
            _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
            if(_rectangle.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                _fillColor = Color.GREEN;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
    
    @Override public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        zoomer = true;
        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
            zoomFactor = Math.max(zoomFactor / 1.1, MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR);
        }
        if (e.getWheelRotation() > 0) {
            zoomFactor = Math.min(zoomFactor * 1.1, MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {} 
    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: There's no relationship between what's been painted and the mouse events been generated by the system.  You'll need to apply your own modifications to the mouse events based on the current zoom factor

Comment: unfortunately I do not know what the translation code is...this is where i need help

Comment: Without actually trying anything, I might simply start with `e.x * zoom` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, that was a little more involved than I first thought.

The "basic" concept is, you need to apply the same `AffineTransformation` you used to paint the component to you `_rectangle`

So, I started by creating an instance property to keep track of the current transformation, as this is going to get re-used a bit

```
private AffineTransform transformation = new AffineTransform();
```

Then I added a getter

```
protected AffineTransform getTransformation() {
    return transformation;
}
```

Then I "optimised" your `paintComponent`, seriously...

```
double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();
```

is a really bad idea, generally, but especially from within a paint pass

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    g2.setTransform(getTransformation());

    g2.setColor(_fillColor);
    g2.fillRect(_rectangle.x, _rectangle.y, _rectangle.width, _rectangle.height);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.drawRect(_rectangle.x, _rectangle.y, _rectangle.width, _rectangle.height);

    g2.dispose();
}
```

I then modified the `mouseWheelMoved` to calculate the new `AffineTransformation` each time it changed

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

    Point2D zoomAnchor = e.getPoint();

    prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
    if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
        zoomFactor = Math.max(zoomFactor / 1.1, MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR);
    }
    if (e.getWheelRotation() > 0) {
        zoomFactor = Math.min(zoomFactor * 1.1, MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR);
    }

    transformation = new AffineTransform();
    double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;
    xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * zoomAnchor.getX();
    yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * zoomAnchor.getX();

    transformation.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
    transformation.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);

    repaint();
}
```

Now, each time `mouseMoved` is called, you need to apply the `AffineTransformation` to the `_rectangle` and check it for any collisions...

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    AffineTransform at = getTransformation();
    PathIterator pathIterator = _rectangle.getPathIterator(at);
    GeneralPath shape = new GeneralPath();
    shape.append(pathIterator, true);
    
    _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
    if (shape.contains(e.getPoint())) {
        _fillColor = Color.GREEN;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Now, I would be tempted to create a "shadow" `Shape` each time `mouseWheelMoved` is called, as you're going to want it for the other mouse events

## Runnable example...

I've not updated your `mousePressed` or `mouseDragged` methods, I'll leave you to do that.  I've also left in some debug code which will draw the "transformed shape" on each paint pass.  This is draw BEFORE the `Graphics` context is transformed, so it should give you a bit of a guide

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new TestPane());
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main demo = new Main();
                    demo.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class TestPane extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final double MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR = 0.1;
        private static final double MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR = 5.0;

        private Color _fillColor;
        private Point _startPoint;
        private double xOffset;
        private double yOffset;

        private int xdragOffset;
        private int ydragOffset;

        private double zoomFactor = 1;
        private double prevZoomFactor = 1;
        private boolean zoomer;
        private Point zoomAnchor;

        private Rectangle _rectangle;

        private AffineTransform transformation = new AffineTransform();

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseWheelListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
            addMouseListener(this);
            _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
            _rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(640, 480);
        }

        // This would be better pre-calculated when the 
        // zoom actually changes
        protected AffineTransform getTransformation() {
            return transformation;
        }

        private Shape testPath;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            if (testPath != null) {
                g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2.draw(testPath);
            }

            g2.setTransform(getTransformation());

            g2.setColor(_fillColor);
            g2.fillRect(_rectangle.x, _rectangle.y, _rectangle.width, _rectangle.height);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.drawRect(_rectangle.x, _rectangle.y, _rectangle.width, _rectangle.height);

            g2.dispose();
        }

        // This is purly for test purposes and you could simply
        // create based on needs at the time
        // Alternativly, you could apply a simular logic to it as the
        // AffineTransformation and each time the zoom is changed,
        // you could create a new, reusable, instance
        protected Shape createTransformedShape() {
            AffineTransform at = getTransformation();
            PathIterator pathIterator = _rectangle.getPathIterator(at);
            GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
            path.append(pathIterator, true);

            testPath = path;
            return path;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            Shape shape = createTransformedShape();

            _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
            if (shape.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                _fillColor = Color.GREEN;
            }
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
//            _startPoint = null;
//            _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
//
//            AffineTransform at = getTransformation();
//            Point2D zoomPoint = zoomedPointFrom(e.getPoint());
//            PathIterator pathIterator = _rectangle.getPathIterator(at);
//            GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
//            path.append(pathIterator, true);
//
//            if (path.contains(zoomPoint)) {
//                _startPoint = e.getPoint();
//                _fillColor = Color.GREEN;
//                xdragOffset = _startPoint.x - _rectangle.x;
//                ydragOffset = _startPoint.y - _rectangle.y;
//            }
//            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
//            if (_startPoint != null) {
//                int diffX = e.getX() - _startPoint.x;
//                int diffY = e.getY() - _startPoint.y;
//
//                _rectangle.x = _startPoint.x + diffX - xdragOffset;
//                _rectangle.y = _startPoint.y + diffY - ydragOffset;
//            } else {
//                _fillColor = Color.WHITE;
//                if (_rectangle.contains(e.getPoint())) {
//                    _fillColor = Color.GREEN;
//                }
//            }
//            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {

            Point2D zoomAnchor = e.getPoint();

            prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
            if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
                zoomFactor = Math.max(zoomFactor / 1.1, MIN_ZOOM_FACTOR);
            }
            if (e.getWheelRotation() > 0) {
                zoomFactor = Math.min(zoomFactor * 1.1, MAX_ZOOM_FACTOR);
            }

            transformation = new AffineTransform();
            double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;
            xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * zoomAnchor.getX();
            yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * zoomAnchor.getX();

            transformation.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
            transformation.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);

            createTransformedShape();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing...I am carefully going through your code to see if I can understand ... I will have a follow up comment shortly

Comment: This might be one of those moments where it might actually be better to apply the transformation JUST to the shapes and not the `Graphics` context, but, needs drive musts

Comment: I see you commented out the drag code for moving the rectangle around the screen. Is that because my old logic no longer works? Also, why did you dispose the graphics context? Isn't that done automatically by swing?

Comment: @NewbieGuest First, look at the `paintComponent` method, I create a copy of the `Graphics` context, `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();`, therefore, I'm responsible for disposing it.  I create a copy, because it's a shared resource, which gets passed to all components involved in the paint pass, this means that any modifications to the context are also passed (like transformations), so I create a copy, make my modifications and then dispose it when I'm done

Comment: @NewbieGuest Second, as I stated "*I've not updated your mousePressed or mouseDragged methods, I'll leave you to do that"*, I commented them out to ensure that they didn't interfere with my other testing.  This far from a complete solution and is intended, instead, to give you a jumping off point, as you could modify your solution in a of different number of ways

Comment: I see... I thought you would have cast it like Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;   I am playing around with your code, it is quite advanced for me ... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some digging on the internet, I found another way to do this...

All the complicated logic remains inside the mouse wheel event...

```
@Override public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    try {
        if (e.getScrollType() == MouseWheelEvent.WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL) {

            double scaleValue = scale - (0.1 * e.getWheelRotation());
            scaleValue = scaleValue < 0.1 ? 0.1 : scaleValue;
            scaleValue = scaleValue > 3 ? 3 : scaleValue;
            scale = scaleValue;
 
            Point2D p1 = e.getPoint();
            Point2D p2 = null;
            p2 = tx.inverseTransform(p1, null);
            tx.setToIdentity();
            tx.translate(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
            tx.scale(scale, scale);
            tx.translate(-p2.getX(), -p2.getY());

            repaint();
        }
    } 
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

In the paintComponent, the call is quite simple:

```
@Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setTransform(tx);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);       
    g2.draw(getBounds());

    g2.setColor(_color);
    g2.fill(rect1);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);       
    g2.draw(rect1);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.draw(rect2);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

All mouse events are handled the same way. I created a routine to convert the original mouse event's coordinates ...

```
private final Point transformMouseEventPoint(MouseEvent event) {
    try {
        Point2D p = tx.inverseTransform(
                event.getPoint(), null);
        return new Point((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY());
    }
    catch(Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This is how it is used

```
@Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    try {
        _color = Color.WHITE;
        _startPoint = null;

        Point p = transformMouseEventPoint(e);

        if(rect1.contains(p)) {
            _color = Color.RED;
            _startPoint = p;
            xOffset = _startPoint.x - (int)rect1.getX();
            yOffset = _startPoint.y - (int)rect1.getY();
        }
        repaint();
    } 
    catch (Throwable e1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e1);
    }
}
```

Next challenge is to add scrollbars to the scaled workspace